# React: how to add a spinner after click, and change screen after the animation completes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw there are already answered questions on how to add spinners during fetch requests.
However what I need is to stop showing the animation when the animation completes. The animation completes after the timeout is reached.

Also I have a best practice question.
It's a good practice to empty the resources on `componentWillUnmount` and clear there the timeout. In the code below I clear the timeout in a `if` condition, because it has to stop as the `height` of the element reaches the right level.

Is that ok as I did it? If now, how should it look like to have the same functionality in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle phase?

Here is the animation Component:

```
class Thermometer extends Component {

    state = {
        termFill : 0
    };

        componentDidMount() {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                this.setState({
                    termFill: this.state.termFill + 10
                });
                if (this.state.termFill === 110) {
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 200)
        }



        render() {
            const styles = {
              height: `${this.state.termFill}px`
            };


            if (this.state.termFill < 100) {

                return (
                    <section>
                                <div id="therm-fill" style={styles} />
                      [MORE CODE - SHORTENED FOR EASIER READING]
            )
        }
    };
```

And here is the Component that has to appear after the animation disappears.
The steps are like this:

1. A user enter and uses this tool
2. The user clicks "calculate"
3. The animation appears instead or on top of the tool
4. When the animation completes, the animation Component disappears and the tool
   is once again visible with its updated state (results of the
   calculation).

   ```
    class DiagnoseTool extends Component {
       state = {
           [OTHER STATES REMOVED TO KEEP THE CODE SHORTER]
           wasBtnClicked: false
       };

           [OTHER RADIO AND CHECKBOX HANDLERS REMOVED TO KEEP THE CODE SHORTER]


   onButtonClick = e => {
       e.preventDefault();
       this.calculate();

       this.setState({
           wasBtnClicked: true
       })
   };


   addResult = () => {

       const resultColor = {
           backgroundColor: "orange"
       };


       let theResult;
           if (this..... [CODE  REMOVED TO HAVE THE CODE SHORTER]
           return theResult;
   };


   calculate = () => {
       let counter = 0;
       let radiocounter = 0;

       Object.keys(this.state).filter(el => ['cough', 'nodes', 'temperature', 'tonsillarex'].includes(el)).forEach(key => {

           // console.log(this.state[key]);
           if (this.state[key] === true) {
               counter += 1;
           }
       });

       if (this.state.radioAge === "age14") {
           radiocounter++
       } else if (this.state.radioAge === "age45") {
           radiocounter--
       }

       if (this.state.radioAge !== "") {
           this.setState({
               isDisabled: false
           })
       }

       this.setState({
           points: counter + radiocounter
       });
   };



   render() {
       const {cough, nodes, temperature, tonsillarex, radioAge, wasBtnClicked} = this.state;
       return (
           <Container>
               <BackArrow />

               [JSX REMOVED TO KEEP THE CODE SHORTER]

                   <div className="resultbox">
                   {
                       (wasBtnClicked) && this.addResult()
                   }
                   </div>
               </div>


      [HERE IS THE BUTTON]
               <button
                   style={{height: "40px", width: "150px", cursor:"pointer"}}
                   type="submit"
                   className="calculateBtn"
                   onClick={this.onButtonClick}
                   disabled={!radioAge}
               >CALCULATE</button>


           </Container>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean to your state and set it to false, when the user clicks the button set it to true, after doing the calculation set it to false.

```
calculate = () => {
  let counter = 0;
  let radiocounter = 0;

  this.setState({
    isLoading: true // set is loading to true and show the spinner
  })

  Object.keys(this.state)
    .filter(el =>
      ["cough", "nodes", "temperature", "tonsillarex"].includes(el)
    )
    .forEach(key => {
      // console.log(this.state[key]);
      if (this.state[key] === true) {
        counter += 1;
      }
    });

  if (this.state.radioAge === "age14") {
    radiocounter++;
  } else if (this.state.radioAge === "age45") {
    radiocounter--;
  }

  if (this.state.radioAge !== "") {
    this.setState({
      isDisabled: false
    });
  }

  this.setState({
    points: counter + radiocounter,
    isLoading: false // set it to false and display the results of the calculation
  });
};
```

Example

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {

  timer = null;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: '',
      isLoading: false
    };
  }
  
  
  
  showContent = () => { this.setState({ isLoading: false, result: `7 + 5 = ${7 + 5}` })}
  
  
  calculate = () => {
  
     this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
      result: ''
     });
     
     this.timer = setTimeout(this.showContent, 5000);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
   clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
  

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <p>7 + 5</p>
      <p>{this.state.result}</p>
      { this.state.isLoading 
        
        ? <p>Calculating...</p>
        : <button onClick={this.calculate}>Calculate</button>
      
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Comment: In the render I put an `if`. `If (!isLoading)` return the result, else return the animation. After clicking the btn the animation appears. Good. However in the React dev tool, I see that after clicking the button the state `isLoading` keeps to be true. It doesn't get false. The animation completes and it doesn't go away. What can I change?

Comment: can't say without seeing the code. share your code here https://codeshare.io/Gbl3O7

Comment: code shared. In case of need I can share the code in github

Comment: Don't you see it here? https://codeshare.io/Gbl3O7
I oopened this in a different pc and it works

Comment: add ```this.setState({
            points: counter + radiocounter,
isLoading: false
        });```

Comment: Done and I've updated the code on codeshare. Still the state doesn't change to false and the animation stays there on even if the animation has completed